# Populate a field using a foreign key on create template using Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have 1 table: "Transactions".
1 table "Employee".

I'm trying to retrieve some information from table "Employee" in Transactions context in order to populate a dropdown menu with id from "Employee" (since every transaction needs to be linked to an Employee). At this time when I run my code, I get no results.

I have a foreign key 'codigo_referido_id' that references to 'id' (from Employee table).

**Transaction Model**

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function employees(){

       return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class , 'codigo_referido_id');

    }
}
```

**Employee Model**

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'employees';
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre',
        'codigo_referido'
    ];


}
```

**TransactionController**

```
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create(Transaction $transaction)
    {
        $transactions = Transaction::all();
        

        return view('transaction.create' , compact('transactions'));
    }
```

Blade template (at the moment I only have this to check the result):

```
{{ dd($transactions->employees()) }}
```

Nonetheless, It'll fill a Select field with the employees.

At this time I get this error:

BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::employees does not exist.

Can someone help me?

Regards

Comment: You are not calling the method properly with . try it with ->

Comment: change `dd($transactions.empleados())` to `dd($transactions->empleados())`

Comment: Thank you for your response Mohammad, changing the method call it now show this: BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::employees does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Transaction::all()` returns a collection, even if that collection only contains a single record. `employees()` is a method on an instance of `Transaction` therefore you will need to iterate over the collection of `Transactions` and call the `employees` method on each iteration.

As an example:

```php
@foreach ($transactions as $transaction)
    {{ dump($transaction->employees) }}
@endforeach
```

Note that if you want the actual `employees` you need to call the relationship without the `()` as otherwise you'll get an instance of the `BelongsTo` relationship back.

**Update**

TransactionController.php

```php
public function create()
{
    return view('transactions.create', [
        'employees' => Employee::all()
    ]);
}

public function show(Transaction $transaction)
{
    return view('transactions.create', [
        'transaction' => $transaction->with('employees')
    ]);
}
```

transactions.create

```
{{-- loop over all employees --}
@foreach ($employees as $employee)
    {{ $employee->id }}
@endforeach
```

transactions.show

```
{{-- get the employee associated to the transaction --}}
{{ $transaction->employees }}
```

Comment: Thank you Peppermintology, now I know that the relationship is working, but I'm not receiving the expected results, using the code you just supplied It shows the entire row of the first "employee (since there's only 1 transaction record on the table If I manually add a second record to Transactions table, It will show two records of the "Employees". Is there any way to show all employees records (since  I want them to populate a HTML select field).

Comment: All employees in your database, or just the employees related to the `Transaction`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Peppermintology, I've already done that but as I mention in my previous comment, I only receive the same amount of employees that records I have on the DB, fo EX: IF I have 10 employees records and only 2 transaction records, it will only show two employees records. I Want to show all employees records.

Comment: "All employees in your database, or just the employees related to the Transaction?"
in transaction.create View to show all employees.  Then when I create the transaction.show View, it will only show the specific employee associated with that transaction.

Comment: @AlexandroGiles I have updated my answer to address your comments.

Comment: Thanks that is what I need, I have 1 last question, Is my Modeling right? I mean I've correctly used: belongsTo? to map that a Transaction must be associated with 1 employee.

Comment: @AlexandroGiles Assuming your `transactions` table has a field for the `employee_id` then `belongsTo` is the correct relationship yes.

Comment: Yes it does @Peppermintology, thank you for your clarification, I've mark you answer as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing all of transactions to `$transactions` variable. In your blade file you are using `{{ dd($transactions->employees()) }}`. The problem is model relation functions should be run on each instance of model not collection of model. `$transactions` is collection of `Transaction` mdoel. Use `foreach` loop to iterate over them:

```
@foreach($transactions as $transaction)
    {{ $transaction->employee() }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Mohammad, the modeling I think is good: 1 Transaction must Belong to 1 employee. Nonetheless I think I'm not understanding how to retrieve All employees to the transaction.create view in order to use it as a constrain when create a new transaction. I want all employees to populate a dropdown menu, to force a user to select an employee when creating a new transaction.

Comment: I get confused. if each transaction has only one employee, so if you want to show all employees just use `Employee::all()`

Comment: yes, that was the answer I misunderstood how the information is retrieved when there's a relation between two tables. Thank you very much